# How to close a group in CiviSEPA

Tags: civisepa

I hope someone here can help me as I´m totally stuck with this problem.

I succesfully created SEPA Mandates, generated a group, downloaded the XML file and transmitted the file to my bank with a banking software today. However, I´m not able to close the group or mark the payments as "recieved". If I click the button "close and submit" ("Schließen und Senden" in German), it allows me to download the XML file, but otherwise says: "This is a test group and therefore can´t be closed". ("Dies ist eine Testgruppe. Sie kann nicht geschlossen werden.").

I´m unable to find out why that is only a test group and how I´m able to mark those payments as "recieved".

Thanks so much for your help!
Angelika

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stack Exchange Angelika. The error is most liekly because your SEPA-creditor is marked as a test creditor. You should be able to change that in the creditor's settings.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! That was the (very easy) solution that I couldn´t find myself. ^^ All the best!